# Alerts based on changes to existing lists

Tags: list

I have created a new list. Users when populating the list items have an option in one field to choose from five selection values(drop-down). For E.g - Alpha, Beta, Gamma. 
I want to create an alert for each of these selection values. If the user has chosen Alpha it should trigger a notification mail to a set of user
Similarly if they choose Beta it should trigger a notification to a different set of users.

How do I go about doing this?

Answer (score 1):

Create a view with a filter for each option.  Then set alerts that are based on each of those views.

List Settings >> (down at the bottom) Create View >> Filter if Column = Beta

Answer (score 1):

That sounds very much like a basic Flow if you are in Office 365. 
If you are on prem I guess you will have to use SPD